# Cutting Wall Tile with Oscillating tool?

Tags: ceramic-tile

Installing a bathroom vanity cabinet.  It fits fine, but I need to cut a half inch of the base board tile (tile along the wall, where it meets floor tile) to have the cabinet flush to the wall.  I recently bought a Bosch 2608661757 Grout and Mortar Remover for my Oscillating tool to remove a layer of grout to regrout floor.  Will I be able to use this accessory to cut this tile on the wall?  Trying not to go buy another saw.  I also have other saw bits, but would like some advice.

Comment: How much tile do you need to cut?

Comment: It is one tile and a half inch needs to come off a 2"x4" tile, on the wall

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to cut the cabinet to fit the tile?  Or is the cabinet concrete or rock, etc.?

Comment: Wow, that was an angle I did not think about.  I have to check the cabinet when I get home from work.

Answer (score 1):

That should cut through the tile fairly well (assuming ceramic and not porcelain), but it may not leave a clean edge against the cabinet. In particular, you'll have trouble getting through the surface glazing.

I'd set the cabinet in place, trace it on the tile with a permanent marker, pop the tile off the wall, and take it to a big box or tile shop and ask them to cut it with their wet saw.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for that advice.  Did not think of the edge it would leave with that tool.  Was looking for a quick solution, but it would have looked horrible and I could not find those tiles around.

Comment: Wet saw is the best way to cut it will leave the cleanest edge.+

Comment: Note that "pop the tile off the wall" might result in breaking the tile. Hope you have spares.